# after update trigger to deal with multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created trigger to log all updated rows either one row or multiple and log updated rows into another table. The trigger is working fine with one record but when I update entire table for example: `update TBL_ADM_USER_GROUP set name = '123'` only one record is logged into `TBL_TestTable` ? why only one row logged into `TBL_TestTable` and how to enable this trigger to log all updated rows ?

trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Group_Update]
ON [dbo].[TBL_ADM_USER_GROUP]

 AFTER UPDATE
  AS
   BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @userid INT
   DECLARE @name nvarchar(1000)

   SELECT @userid = i.changer_user_id from inserted i; 
   select @name = i.name from inserted i;

   INSERT INTO TBL_TestTable
   VALUES (CONCAT('Group "' ,@name,'" is updated'), 'GROUP', 'Update', SYSDATETIME(), @userid)

END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `SQL Server` trigger works per entire statement, not row by row. Use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Group_Update]
ON [dbo].[TBL_ADM_USER_GROUP]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO TBL_TestTable    -- define column list for clarity
   SELECT CONCAT('Group "' ,i.name,'" is updated'),
         'GROUP', 'Update', SYSDATETIME(),
         i.changer_user_id
   FROM inserted i;
END
```

Comment: how to make  userid equal to changer_user_id as shown in question?

Comment: @Smart You can't. `@userid` is scalar variable and can hold only one value at time so when you use: `SELECT @userid = i.changer_user_id from inserted i; ` you get probably last value from `inserted` table dependent on execution plan.

Comment: what you said is totally true, but how to use the declared parameters userid and name?

Comment: You don't need scalar variables, they can't hold multiple rows.